# Difference between www.sub.example.com and sub.example.com

Tags: domain-name-system, website, linked-server

I want to know the difference between these two links to my site:

- My site https://rahul62888282.000webhostapp.com is working as supposed.
- https://www.rahul62888282.000webhostapp.com (with www) is showing me a **privacy error**.

Comment: Inspect the certificate and you'll see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Wildcard certificates covers only one level of subdomains. [RFC 2818, 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1):

> Matching is performed using the matching rules specified by [RFC2459](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2459).
> If more than one identity of a given type is present in the
> certificate (e.g., more than one `dNSName` name, a match in any one of
> the set is considered acceptable.) Names may contain the wildcard
> character `*` which is considered to match any single domain name
> component or component fragment. E.g., `*.a.com` matches `foo.a.com` but
> not `bar.foo.a.com`.

Your `*.000webhostapp.com` matches `rahul62888282.000webhostapp.com`, not its subdomains.